# Why my question was closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

My question: [Does quantum mechanics prohibit extraterrestrial life?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7702/does-quantum-mechanics-prohibit-extraterrestrial-life-closed)

has been closed as "off-topic" with a reference to the FAQ (https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq). I have read the FAQ and found nothing that could prohibit that kind of questions.

It is true that the question is heavily based on the "quantum immortality" hypothesis which is not universally accepted, and I was attacked for referencing to this hypothesis as well as the Tegmark's interpretation of Quantum mechanics.

But I believe that "quantum immortality" hypothesis even if incorrect, still is a completely valid one, and supported by a number of prominent physicists.

I oppose closing questions based on personal theoretic preferences.

Answer (score 4):

Several people were in favor of closing your question, and I can't speak for all of them, but the original reason I closed it was that the "quantum immortality" idea you spoke of seemed like abstract speculation, not physics. The fact that you didn't link to any resources to give background information on your question certainly played a role in that.

After a second look, I searched the web for information and read a little more about this quantum immortality idea. Although I still have my doubts about whether it is legitimate physics, I decided to reclassify the closing as "not a real question" because I don't see how you're making a coherent argument. Questions on the interpretations of quantum mechanics are always iffy, and if you are not very careful to stick to rigorous arguments, it greatly increases the chance that your question will be closed. The question as it stands *might* be appropriate for a philosophy site.

Keep in mind that I'm not the only one who thought it was appropriate to close the question. Perhaps others will add their input.

Answer (score 3):

Quantum immortality is a silly idea and piling more layers of deductions (logically unsound too, by the way) upon it can't possibly lead to anything else than arguments and quarrels. And even if everything was logically sound and in the boundaries of reasonable theoretical physics, I still wouldn't see any real value in the question. I believe all of this gives plenty of reasons to close.

If you want to have any chance of turning this into a normal question, you might ask about the nature of quantum immortality itself and how people view it (a bit subjective though). This would have at least some value of addressing some useless thought experiments and misconceptions arising from them.

Comment: I think asking about QI is quite trivial. My question was about one of its implications.